# Splitting table by column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, join

I have 4 tables I want to join to display items sold and items returned.  The issue I'm having is that the sold and returned items are in the same table and I'm having trouble returning a 0 for the 'Return' column when an item is sold without returns and a 0 for the 'Sold' column when an item is returned without a sale.  Here's what I'm trying to do,

Locations

```
LocationID LocationName
    1           NY
    2           LA
    3        Chicago
```

Items

```
ItemID ItemName
   A   Sandwich
   B    Salad
   C     Wrap
```

Deliveries

```
DeliveryID LocationID
    1          1
    2          2
    3          3
    4          1
```

DeliveryRecords

```
RecordID DeliveryID ItemID Quantity RecordType
    1         1       A       3        SOLD
    2         1       B       4        SOLD
    3         1       C       5        SOLD
    4         1       C       2       RETURN
    5         2       A       3        SOLD
    6         2       B       2        SOLD
    7         3       B       2        SOLD
    8         3       C       3        SOLD
    9         4       A       1       RETURN
```

And I want my query to return,

```
Location DeliveryID    Item      Sold Returned
  NY         1        Sandwich     3     0
  NY         1         Salad       4     0
  NY         1         Wrap        5     2
  LA         2        Sandwich     3     0
  LA         2         Salad       2     0
Chicago      3         Salad       2     0
Chicago      3         Wrap        3     0
  NY         4         Wrap        0     1
```

Comment: What is the query that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation (after a bunch of joins):

```
select l.locationname, dr.deliveryid, i.itemname,
       sum(case when dr.recordtype = 'SOLD' then quantity else 0 end) as sold,
       sum(case when dr.recordtype = 'RETURN' then quantity else 0 end) as returned
from deliveryrecords dr join
     deliveries d
     on dr.deliveryid = d.deliveryid join
     location l
     on d.locationid = l.locationid join
     items i
     on dr.itemid = i.itemid
group by l.locationname, dr.deliveridy, i.itemname;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Using `JOIN` and `SUM`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4040/0)

```
SELECT
    l.LocationName,
    dr.DeliveryID,
    i.ItemName,
    [Sold]      = SUM(CASE WHEN dr.RecordType = 'SOLD' THEN dr.Quantity ELSE 0 END),
    [Returned]  = SUM(CASE WHEN dr.RecordType = 'RETURN' THEN dr.Quantity ELSE 0 END)
FROM DeliveryRecords dr
INNER JOIN Items i
    ON i.ItemID = dr.ItemId
INNER JOIN Deliveries d
    ON d.DeliveryID = dr.DeliveryID
INNER JOIN Locatins l
    ON l.LocationID = d.LocationId
GROUP BY
    dr.DeliveryID, l.LocationName, i.ItemName
```